# Adding element to datalist

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Let's say, I have such `.xhtml`

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataList id="carList" value="#{myBean.cars}" var="car">
        #{car.brand}, #{car.year}
    </p:dataList>

    <p:commandButton value="Add new car" actionListener="#{myBean.addCar}" update="@form"/>
</h:form>
```

After pressing `Add new car` button, a new car object is added to `myBean.cars` and dataList is fully rerendered. Ajax response with changes contains not only new car, but all existing cars and new one.

Since I have more complex model and large set of data, it's very time consuming to rerender all elements. Is it possible to add new element without rerendering all existing elements of list?

Comment: No, not directly in this way. But I'm thinking about starting to implement a feature for some of these PrimeFaces components, but this won't be ready within 2 months.

Comment: if you can use other components, then datatable supports lazy loading and fetching (displaying only some records from big record set)